# Masking tape on 12v car charger adapter a fire hazard?

Tags: voltage, power, amperage

I recently purchased a 12v USB car charger adapter (for context https://www.bestbuy.com/site/anker-powerdrive-2-alloy-24w-vehicle-charger-silver/6479184.p) to power my phone. Due to vibrations, the adapter comes loose after some time driving and to fix that I decided to put some blue masking tape on the body of the adapter to make it have a tighter fit.

Since the 12v car socket shell acts as the negative terminal, is there a risk of fire danger with the electrical current heating up the masking tape and starting a fire? The adapter would be running at 5v at 12 watts and since I would be charging my phone, I assume the current is something between 1-2amps. Obviously, I could replace the masking tape with electrical tape but wondering if this is necessary.

Comment: Sounds OK as the ring wont get hot enough to even light a cigarette or even get warm unlike a cigarette lighter.

Comment: Does the junction you're concerned about get warm/hot while charging your phone?   If not, don't sweat it.

Comment: Also...  A thought about your problem.  You might try putting a simple rubber O-ring around the adaptor to get it to stick in the socket better.  Any hardware store will have a large assortment of O-rings.  (And that won't catch fire either  ;)  )

Comment: masking tape is good to higher temperatures than most plastics, the glue tends turn to powder with age though

Answer (score 1):

While it seems very unlikely that you would have a fire from this, I will simply mention that "Kapton" tape is much more temperature resistant than masking tape, and is frequently used in electronics applications for a variety of purposes. So you might consider purchasing a roll of Kapton tape.

Kapton is a brand name for polyimide film tape.

Here is a picture of a small battery with kapton tape wrapped around the top of it.

Image source: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6a/Kapton_Tape.png
According to source, image is licensed under Creative Commons Attribution-Share Alike 4.0 International License.

[image: kapton tape over battery]